# How to join a table on two columns by selecting max value? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I am working on a View and have the following table which I try to modify. (SQL Server)

Table X

```
ID    Value  End_time
1     10     2019-12-06T07:00:00+0000
2     15     2020-01-07T07:00:00+0000
2     20     2020-01-31T07:00:00+0000
3     25     2020-02-02T07:00:00+0000
3     30     2020-02-28T07:00:00+0000
4     35     2020-03-05T07:00:00+0000
4     40     2020-03-31T07:00:00+0000
```

The [End_time] has to be converted from varchar into date and further splitter in month and year, then I have to select the max date and group by the data by year and month.

So I make the following query

```
SELECT        [ID], [Value], CONVERT(date, LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14)) AS [date], 
              -- convert to date

              MONTH(CONVERT(date, LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))) AS Month_Name, --get month
              YEAR(CONVERT(date, LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))) AS Year_Name --get year
FROM            X AS Table 
                INNER JOIN --join on itself
                (SELECT MAX([date]) AS MaxDate, MONTH([date]) AS Month_Name, YEAR(date) AS Year_Name
                 FROM X
                 GROUP BY MONTH([date]), YEAR([date])) AS D ON D.MaxDate = CONVERT(date, 
                                                         LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))
```

But I get an error that there's no such column as date. 
I tried to join like this:

```
INNER JOIN --join on itself
                    (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(date, LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))) AS MaxDate, 
                     MONTH([date]) AS Month_Name, YEAR(date) AS Year_Name
                     FROM X
                     GROUP BY MONTH([date]), YEAR([date])) AS D ON D.MaxDate = CONVERT(date, 
                                                             LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))
```

But then I get the error that The multi-part identifier "X.End_time" could not be bound.

So my ideal result is

```
ID    Value  Month_Name Year_Name
1     10     12         2019
2     35     01         2020
3     55     02         2020
4     75     03         2020
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use:

```
select id, value,
       substring(endtime, 5, 2) as month,
       left(endtime, 4) as year
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by endtime desc) as seqnum
      from x
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Although storing a date/time value as a string is a bad choice of representation, you have at least chosen a very good format for the string.  You can just order by the string to get the most recent or oldest row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX([table_alias.ID]), 
       SUM([table_alias.VALUE]), 
       [table_alias.Month_Name], 
       [table_alias.Year_Name]
FROM ( SELECT  [ID], [Value], 
        MONTH(CONVERT(date, LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))) AS Month_Name,
        YEAR(CONVERT(date, LEFT([End_time], LEN([End_time]) - 14))) AS Year_Name 
FROM  X) AS table_alias 
group by [table_alias.Month_Name], 
       [table_alias.Year_Name]
```